# Play framework find list by list

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I use Play framework 1.2.7.

Lets say I have three models, `Picture` and `Feed`, which both have a `@ManyToMany` connection to `Tag`. Now in the `Feed` model I'd like to add two methods:

- get all `Pictures` where all tags from `Feed.tags` exists in `Picture.tags` (if `Picture` has additional tags that's still OK).
- get all `Pictures` where at least one tag from `Feed.tags` exists in `Picture.tags`

I know this can be done in code, but if possible I'd like to do it in a statement. Anyone got any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my knowledge, we CANNOT do it in just 1 query statement, you should implement in other way.

But, shortest way is using `Criteria` class with `Query` class to provide a statement with AND/OR operator.